# Launching an Alarm Alert from app

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a stock market alert app that will launch an alarm when a specific price is hit. How do I call or create an alarm from my app?

Comment: Have you even Googled how to use push notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as I see it, you have two ways..

1.- **Register your app for background fetch**

This way every while (***when** is up to iOS*) you will be granted the possibility to connect to the internet. At this moment, if something **hits** any of your alarms you can go for the approach of sending an `UILocalNotification`.

If you go for local notifications alone, without the ability to fetch when your app is officially off, then you will only receive notifications..(your alarms) when you are inside of your app.

> **Downside of this approach**: You alarm will not be exact and maybe you lose some alarms along the way as maybe the stock market comes into a **hit** point, but then it has already come to normal when the **iOS background fetch mechanism** decides to let you connect.

2.- **Register your app for push notifications**
*(As @WMios suggested in a comment before)*

The way to go (as of my point of view) is using **push notifications**.

For this approach you will need to have a **webservice** listening constantly to the stock market (*here you can use any technology or language as that doesn't matter for the mechanism to work*), and **register** your user needs into this server (*you will be **observing*** for those **hits** for every one of your users), every user will have its **PUSH_ID** (a way in wish push notifications will be sent to a unique device) registered into your webservice and when the alarm goes on, you will send an **"special"** message to Apple Servers *(including a **message** (what will be shown to the user) and the **PUSH_ID** you gathered from your user's device*).

There are several tutorials about this regard around the web, so you will have no problems finding a good one.

> **Hint**: You may want to redirect the user directly from the notification that appears into where he can see why the alarm was triggered, but, this is up to you :)
>
> **Downside of this approach**: If an alarm is triggered (and sends a push notification) when the user is inside the app. Then the notification will not be shown, take this into account when deciding how you will be checking for those alarms when the user is inside your app.

3.- **A mixture of both approachs** (Yes, a third..even if I wrote other thing before)

There's not much to say here, only that by this way you may be able to attack the downsides of both previous approach.

**Happy coding! ;-)**

Answer (score -1):

UILocalNotifications is a possibility

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.alertBody = @"YOURMESSAGE";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/

Answer (score -1):

Swift version:

```
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = targetDate
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    notification.alertAction = "do a task"
    notification.alertBody = "New task is waiting for you!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```